# React JS and a leaked input

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, reactjs

I'm new to React JS (using v0.10.0), and I'm trying to fix a memory leak in my project. Here's what I'm doing to render the page in question...

```
var mainContent = React.createClass({
    /*...various functions for handling state changes...*/
    render: function() {
        return React.DOM.div({
            children: [
                /*...some children...*/
                React.DOM.input({
                    id: 'quizname-textbox',
                    type: 'text',
                    className: 'textfield text-entry-toggle-textbox',
                    value: this.state.value,
                    autoComplete:"off",
                    autoCorrect: "off", 
                    autoCapitalize: "off", 
                    placeholder: gettext('Name Your Quiz...'), 
                    maxLength: "255",
                    onBlur: this.handleBlur,
                    onChange: this.handleChange
                }),
                /*...more children...*/
            ]
        });
    }
});

React.renderComponent(mainContent, document.getElementById('main-content'));
```

...and when I navigate away from the page, I'm doing this:

`React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('main-content'));`

The call to `unmountComponentAtNode()` returns true, indicating that the component was successfully removed. However if I then take a heap snapshot using Chrome's developer tools, I see a detached DOM tree that contains all the elements that were just on the page. The input element from above is the only yellow element—meaning there's still a JavaScript reference to it—so it's likely causing the entire page to be leaked (see screenshot). I can't figure out why there's still a reference to that input—I'm not explicitly adding any other event listeners to it, and it is not referenced inside either `this.handleBlur()` or `this.handleChange()`. Moreover, if I simply comment that input out of the list of children, the problem completely goes away (the DOM tree no longer shows up in the detached list).

This is perhaps the strangest clue of all: The heap snapshot says the input is a property of the window object named `elt`; however, I'm not giving it that name and I'm certainly not explicitly adding it directly to the window object.

Any ideas why this input is still hanging around?

[image: heap snapshot showing leak]

Comment: Could you post some more from the class?

Comment: @Eelke The class is pretty big (over 1,500 lines of code). Is there something specific you might want to see?

Comment: well... specifically the source of the leak :) any references to `this`

Comment: Do you have any third party libraries interacting or any browser extensions?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks for your suggestion—indeed the leak _was_ caused by a browser extension named [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/). It's a password manager that does some dynamic things to input elements, and evidently stores references to them on the global object. Once I disabled the extension, the leak promptly stopped. I'll be reporting a bug to them next. Lesson learned: If you want to find a JavaScript/DOM memory leak, disable extensions!